# What does Mat::checkVector do in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, mat, assertion

I tried to use the following function in OpenCV (C++)

```
calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prev_frame_gray, frame_gray, points[0], points[1], status, err, winSize, 3, termcrit, 0, 0.001);
```

and I get this error

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((npoints = prevPtsMat.checkVector(2, CV_32F, true)) >= 0) in calcOpticalFlowPyrLK,
file /home/rohit/OpenCV_src/opencv-2.4.9/modules/video/src/lkpyramid.cpp, line 845
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  /home/rohit/OpenCV_src/opencv-2.4.9/modules/video/src/lkpyramid.cpp:845:
error: (-215) (npoints = prevPtsMat.checkVector(2, CV_32F, true)) >= 0 in function calcOpticalFlowPyrLK
```

Both of the following return -1

```
frame_gray.checkVector(2, CV_32F, true)
prev_frame_gray.checkVector(2, CV_32F, true)
```

I wanted to know what checkVector actually does because it is leading to the assertion error as you can see above.

Comment: Please provide the definition of the input variables/parameters of `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK`

Comment: I forgot to add the definitions. But, It's solved now. Basically, I hadn't initialized points[0] and hence the error. I would still like to know what checkVector does as I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The official OpenCV's doc says:

> [`cv::Mat::checkVector()`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a39541d4dbd7fafbfae93f1737e51ffbc) returns N if the matrix is 1-channel (N x
>   ptdim) or ptdim-channel (1 x N) or (N x 1); negative number otherwise

OpenCV considers some data types equivalent in case of some functions i.e. `objectPoints` of [`cv::solvePnP()`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga549c2075fac14829ff4a58bc931c033d) can be:

- 1xN/Nx1 1-channel `cv::Mat`
- 3xN/Nx3 3-channel `cv::Mat`
- `std::vector<cv::Point3f>`

With `checkVector` you can make sure that you are passing the correct representation of your data.

Comment: What is the definition of 'N' here? Cannot find it in the documentation.

Comment: it's a bit confusing, does this means that the data is continues?

Comment: N just stands for a list of "N" points, 1, 2, 3, ...  whatever the count of N points happens to be.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with cv2.projectPoints function (-215:Assertion failed) because openCV was expecting a nx3 matrix and i was passing an 1D array of length 3. Try:

```
points[0].reshape(-1,3)
```

As argument to the function. It changes the shape (3,) to shape (1,3).