# How to solve Assertion Error when using solvePnP?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv-solvepnp

I'm newbie in Visual Odometry and is following the tutorial of solving VO using PnP. However when I run the program, I get the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(4.3.0) /home/wctu/opencv-4.3.0/modules/calib3d/src/solvepnp.cpp:754: error: (-215:Assertion failed) ( (npoints >= 4) || (npoints == 3 && flags == SOLVEPNP_ITERATIVE && useExtrinsicGuess) ) && npoints == std::max(ipoints.checkVector(2, CV_32F), ipoints.checkVector(2, CV_64F)) in function 'solvePnPGeneric'
```

My code is below:

```
string datas[2266];
string str1;
std::getline(file, str1);
datas[0] = str1;
for(int i = 1; !file.eof(); i++)
   {
      string str;
      std::getline(file, str);
      datas[i] = str;
      if(str.empty()) break;
      if(str.at(0) == '#') continue; /* comment */
      cout << datas[i-1] << endl << datas[i] << endl;
      Mat image, depth, image1, depth1;
      string rgbFilename1 = datas[i-1].substr(timestampLength + 1, rgbPathLehgth );
      string timestap1 = datas[i-1].substr(0, timestampLength);
      string depthFilename1 = datas[i-1].substr(2*timestampLength + rgbPathLehgth + 3, depthPathLehgth );

      image1 = imread(dirname + rgbFilename1);
      depth1 = imread(dirname + depthFilename1, -1);
      string rgbFilename = str.substr(timestampLength + 1, rgbPathLehgth );
      string timestap = str.substr(0, timestampLength);
      string depthFilename = str.substr(2*timestampLength + rgbPathLehgth + 3, depthPathLehgth );

      image = imread(dirname + rgbFilename);
      depth = imread(dirname + depthFilename, -1);
      CV_Assert(!image.empty());
      CV_Assert(!depth.empty());
      CV_Assert(depth.type() == CV_16UC1);

      cout << i << " " << rgbFilename << " " << depthFilename << endl;

      std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1, keypoints_2;
      vector<DMatch> matches;
      find_feature_matches(image1, image, keypoints_1, keypoints_2, matches);
      cout << "一共找到了" << matches.size() << "组匹配点" << endl;
   
//   // 建立3D点
//Mat d1 = imread(depth1, IMREAD_UNCHANGED);       // 深度图为16位无符号数，单通道图像
      Mat K = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 525.0f, 0, 319.5f, 0, 525.0f, 239.5f, 0, 0, 1);
      vector<Point3f> pts_3d;
      vector<Point2f> pts_2d;
      for (DMatch m:matches) {
         ushort d = depth1.ptr<unsigned short>(int(keypoints_1[m.queryIdx].pt.y))[int(keypoints_1[m.queryIdx].pt.x)];
         if (d == 0)   // bad depth
            continue;
         float dd = d / 5000.0;
         Point2d p1 = pixel2cam(keypoints_1[m.queryIdx].pt, K);
         pts_3d.push_back(Point3f(p1.x * dd, p1.y * dd, dd));
         pts_2d.push_back(keypoints_2[m.trainIdx].pt);
      }
      cout << pts_3d[0] << " " << pts_2d[0] << endl;
      cout << "3d-2d pairs: " << pts_3d.size() << " " << pts_2d.size() <<  endl;
   
      chrono::steady_clock::time_point t1 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
      Mat r, t;
      solvePnP(pts_3d, pts_2d, K, Mat(), r, t, false); // 调用OpenCV 的 PnP 求解，可选择EPNP，DLS等方法
      Mat R;
      cv::Rodrigues(r, R); // r为旋转向量形式，用Rodrigues公式转换为矩阵
      chrono::steady_clock::time_point t2 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
      chrono::duration<double> time_used = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::duration<double>>(t2 - t1);
      cout << "solve pnp in opencv cost time: " << time_used.count() << " seconds." << endl;
```

the argv[1] is the text file that associates the rgb image with the depth, and the form is below:

```
1311877977.445420 rgb/1311877977.445420.png 1311877977.431871 depth/1311877977.431871.png
```

I've searched for the solutions online and try everything, but still in vain.

I really appreciate your guys' help, thanks in advance.

**Update:
The inputs that occurs exception are below, there are only three pairs:

```
[0.94783, -1.70307, 7.3738] [383.4, 121.828]
[0.170393, -0.170453, 1.3256] [379.817, 186.325]
[0.610124, -0.161545, 3.4604] [403.108, 223.949]
```

Comment: The assertion already tells you that it failed inside the routine `solvePnP` and tells you which checks it performed: The input parameters you give it are not right. What is your output of `pts_3d.size()`? Did you only copy-paste the code or did you modify it in some way?

Comment: I've modified some of them, but to fit in my input data. The size of pts_3d and pts_2d are 3, so there are three pairs of points to be used in solvePnP, and the input that occurs exception is shown above. They have three dims and two dims respectively, and I thought that was the right input, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **OpenCV function `cv::solvePnP` makes checks internally if the input data you supplied actually makes sense** and actually matches the documentation (assertion). In your case it fails to do so and therefore throws an error message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  OpenCV(4.3.0) /home/wctu/opencv-4.3.0/modules/calib3d/src/solvepnp.cpp:754: error:
(-215:Assertion failed)
( (npoints >= 4) || (npoints == 3 && flags == SOLVEPNP_ITERATIVE && useExtrinsicGuess) ) && 
npoints == std::max(ipoints.checkVector(2, CV_32F), ipoints.checkVector(2, CV_64F)) in function 'solvePnPGeneric'
```

So dimensions of the inputs are not right or the files you are using are not appropriate. The error is given in terms of its input arguments. Therefore you will have to look for the corresponding documentation of [`cv::solvePnP`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga549c2075fac14829ff4a58bc931c033d).

```
bool cv::solvePnP(InputArray  objectPoints,
                  InputArray  imagePoints,
                  InputArray  cameraMatrix,
                  InputArray  distCoeffs,
                  OutputArray rvec,
                  OutputArray tvec,
                  bool        useExtrinsicGuess = false,
                  int         flags = SOLVEPNP_ITERATIVE 
)
```

Comparing your input arguments to the ones given above you will see that you set `useExtrinsicGuess` to false and did not supply `flags` which defaults to `SOLVEPNP_ITERATIVE`. This already tells you that your error isn't caused by `(npoints == 3 && flags == SOLVEPNP_ITERATIVE && useExtrinsicGuess)` (as `useExtrinsicGuess` is set to `false`) but instead by `(npoints >= 4)`.

Opening the corresponding [source-code file on Github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/solvepnp.cpp) or in your source-code folder you will actually see that `npoints` is defined as

```
int npoints = std::max(opoints.checkVector(3, CV_32F), opoints.checkVector(3, CV_64F));
```

Now we have to figure out what `checkVector` does: [See e.g. here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30096493/9938686) It checks the channels and depth of the matrix and returns `-1 if the requirement is not satisfied. Otherwise, it returns the number of elements in the matrix. Note that an element may have multiple channels.`.

This means your code is failing either because the supplied input format for the two data types is not correct or `npoints` is smaller than `4`.

If you again look at the documentation it tells you that `objectPoints` expects `Array of object points in the object coordinate space, Nx3 1-channel or 1xN/Nx1 3-channel, where N is the number of points. vector<Point3d> can be also passed here.`  while `imagePoints` expects an `Array of corresponding image points, Nx2 1-channel or 1xN/Nx1 2-channel, where N is the number of points.`

This is clearly fulfilled by the input `pts_3d` and `pts_2d` that you pass as they are `std::vector<Point3f>`  and `std::vector<Point3f>` respectively. This means the only logical reason is that **`pts_3d` and/or `pts2d` have actually less than 3 entries** which is too little for a unique solution. This means there are **insufficient feature matches found in between the supplied images in the step before!**. Check again your input files and potentially try with different ones.

Comment: So you mean just like above, if I only get 3 pairs of points, it will return error? How can that be solved, cause the input images are continuous, I can't delete the image or skip it, or should I try a different feature detector? I use the ORB though.

Comment: @Peter24 3 points will not work. You will need at least 4 points as pointed out above. Normally finding 4 features in an image shouldn't be a problem. Is there a lot of motion in the picture? Without sample images I can't tell you more.
So first check the output: If it outputs three right before then we are on the right path. If it does try another simple input to see if that works. If it fails as well then probably something is wrong with the feature matching in general. If it works then maybe your input is not appropriate.

Comment: Ok, I found out that it's the descriptors that is empty, which has no keypoints and that's why I keep getting errors, so I decide to change a detector to see if it works. Thanks for ur help!